# Can an off-diagonal-negative matrix have both: a unique negative eigenvalue and a positive row-sum?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

Let $M\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ be a symmetric matrix, all whose off-diagonal entries are non-positive (problem variant: negative). Can the following be true at the same time?

- $M$ has a *unique* negative eigenvalue $\theta<0$ (of multiplicity 1).
- $M$ has at least one row whose entries sum up to a positive (problem variant: non-negative) number.

By [Perron-Frobenius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Non-negative_matrices) I know that $\theta$ has an eigenvector $v\in\Bbb R^n$ with positive entries (we might assume that the matrix is irreducible in the sense required by Perron-Frobenius). If $v$ were $(1,...1)$, this would answer the question in the negative, but in general we don't have this.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the matrix $$M = \begin{bmatrix}2 & -1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$ Clearly, $M$ is square and symmetric, and all of the off-diagonal entries of $M$ are negative. The sum of the elements in the first row of $M$ is positive. Also, the eigenvalues of $M$ are $1+\sqrt{2} > 0$ and $1-\sqrt{2} < 0$, so $M$ has a unique negative eigenvalue of multiplicity $1$..

Comment: Thanks for this example! It definitely helped me to understand the problem better. But it also showed me that in the specific application that I have in mind I might need one more condition that I have not recognized as important so far: the second smallest eigenvalue should be zero. I can consider the matrix $M-(1+\sqrt 2)I$ using your example, but unfortunately this has no positive row sums anymore. Do you see a way to fix this?

Comment: You'll likely need to look at $3 \times 3$ matrices to find a counterexample.